# Sass @each return error: expected `in` keyword in @each directive

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to set the `font-size`/`line-height` for my theme header by using the following code, and I am getting the error `path-to-my-script/general:40 error: expected 'in' keyword in @each directive`

```
$i : 1;

@each $zSize, $zLine in (34, 42), (26, 32)
{
    h#{$i}
    {
        font   : #{$zSize}px/#{$zLine}px $body-font-family !important;
    }

    $i: $i + 1;
}
```

I try to execute this code, based on the SASS Documentation for `@foreach` with [`Multiple Assignments`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive)

Any idea on how to solve this issue ? Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Check your version of Sass.  The feature you're referencing is new for 3.3.  If you're using another application (such as Compass) on top of Sass, make sure it is compatible with this version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output I get from **3.3.6** of SASS from your code is:

```
h1 {
  font: 34px/42px serif !important;
} 

h2 {
  font: 26px/32px serif !important;
}
```

Is that the correct output? Is that the final output?

I get a similar error when I do version **3.2.19** of SASS:

```
Invalid CSS after "@each $zSize": expected "in", was ", $zLine in (34..."
```

What version of SASS are you using? I think you need to expect to use [`@each`](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while#each) differently based on the SASS version.

Answer (score -1):

I have implement another solution for this issue. Here hou can see the new implementation:

```
$i                  : 1;

@each $zSizes in (34, 42), (26, 32), (20, 28), (18, 24), (16, 22), (14, 20)
{
    h#{$i}
    {
        font   : #{rem-calc(nth($zSizes, 1))}/#{rem-calc(nth($zSizes, 2))} $body-font-family !important;
    }

    $i: $i + 1;
}
```